# Align text center dynamically in knockout simplegrid

Tags: knockout.js, grid

I am using knockout simplegrid and want to display one of column in center.

I tried to add below code with text-align: centre to initiate simple grid in my view model

```
this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
    data: this.items,
    columns: [
        { headerText: "Item Name", rowText: "name" },
        { headerText: "Sales Count", rowText: "sales",text-align: "center" },
        { headerText: "Price", rowText: function (item) { return "$" + item.price.toFixed(2) } }
    ],
    pageSize: 4
});
```

But it throws me error **Unexpected token -**

I also added one observable simplegrids view model which is `this.textAlign = ko.observable("left");`

I added value "left" because that will be default. But i dont know how do i make use of this observable in the simplegrid viewmodel.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QSRBR/5199/)

Waiting eagerly for feedback from you intelligent guys.

**Update1**

I know understood why i was getting "unexpected token - " error. Its because it was expecting javascript style name for text-align. The equivalent javascript style name is **textAlign** which is without **-**. I got this info from this [Page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html)

But i still cant dynamically bind text to center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality of the knockout simplegrid is very limited so you need to add this functionality yourself.

You have to extend the `"ko_simpleGrid_grid"` template and add a `style` binding on the gnerated `td` with:

```
<tr data-bind=\"foreach: $parent.columns\">\
      <td data-bind=\"text: typeof rowText == 'function' ? \
          rowText($parent) : $parent[rowText], style: $data.cellStyle \"></td>\
</tr>\
```

And now you can pass in any valid `style` binding value with:

```
columns: [
            { headerText: "Item Name", rowText: "name" },
            { headerText: "Sales Count", rowText: "sales", 
              cellStyle: { textAlign: "center" } },
            { headerText: "Price", 
                rowText: function (item) { return "$" + item.price.toFixed(2) } }
        ],
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GQ3b9/).